# Ideas on jQuery window.send_to_editor with custom textarea?

Tags: jquery

I am using 'shortcodes ultimate', you can click a button next to the wordpress media uploader. When you select your shortcode it is inserted with `window.send_to_editor`.

This is great, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to write it so that I can use it with multiple custom text-area's.

I added the button that is next to the wordpress media uploader to every text-area below the tiny-mce (not totally relevant to know that), essentially its a button that opens thickbox and has a lot of options and stuff. There is a button above each text-area, most likely I am going to need to modify the code, here is an example of what I have in mind.

My code working adjusting due to multiple text-areas and buttons (just wrote this up now, not sure if this is the proper approach)?

```
    $('#generator-insert').each(function() {

    $(this).live('click', function(event) {

        //Lots of code here to build up the values, not needed for this example

        var shortcode = jQuery('#generator-result').val();

        //Perhaps an if statement using the class the click came from here so we know
        //if we should send_to_editor or custom text-area, just not sure what to write
        //to send to the text-area the click came from?

        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'send_to_editor') {
            window.send_to_editor(shortcode);
        } else {
            // Not quite sure what to write here to send to the text-area which the 
            // click came from, I should look up "window" and write something here.
            // I just am a little lost and need some helpful insight...
        }

    });

    });
```

Here is the original version

```
    $('#generator-insert').live('click', function(event) {

    //The generated value data here not needed for this question

    var shortcode = jQuery('#generator-result').val();

    // Insert into widget
    if ( typeof window.generator_target !== 'undefined' ) {
        jQuery('textarea#' + window.generator_target).val( jQuery('textarea#' + window.generator_target).val() + shortcode);
        tb_remove();
    }

    // Insert into editor
    else {
        window.send_to_editor(shortcode);
    }

    // Prevent default action
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

One thing I do note here is `window.generator_target` I feel like this is how you insert it into a custom area. Not quite sure and would love some help.

Another note, the button in each text area is raw html to open the thickbox.. to open the main thickbox next to the wordpress uploader I use `add_action` and insert it that way.. don't think that makes a difference though..

Comment: You should use `classes`, not multiple elements with the same `id` value.

Comment: Are you referring to `#generator-insert`... I need an `.each` because the number of text-area's vary.. Guess I could use numbers? but I am thinking the insert button for one needs to be changed to match the textarea, then I could append to it?

Comment: That's fine, you can do a `.each` on elements with the same class.  You shouldn't perform a `.each` on element ids ever, because their should only be 1 element with that `id`!  Maybe you should post up how the HTML is laid out...

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now.. thats a simple fix. I am not sure what HTML to provide, but really all I want to do is insert the value generated into the text-area which the click came from.

Comment: For starters, the HTML that displays the `text-areas` on your page?

Comment: There is so much code surrounding each textarea but just imagine it like this `<div><a href="opens_my_thickbox"></a><textarea></textarea></div>`
   
`<div><a href="opens_my_thickbox"></a><textarea></textarea></div>` 
   
`<div><a href="opens_my_thickbox"></a><textarea></textarea></div>`

Comment: I could generate a class for each one of those and match the insert button with which it came from? Even if something like that works.. whats the best way to insert content similar to `window.send_to_editor(shortcode)`

Comment: Have a look here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/how-to-handle-multiple-instance-of-send-to-editor-js-function or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671550/jquery-window-send-to-editor or better yet here:  http://codeblow.com/questions/jquery-window-send-to-editor/

Comment: looks like you can use:  `$(this).data('unqiue-id');` to get the id value.