# Wordpress window.send_to_editor conflicts with CKeditor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ckeditor

I searched a day but i did not find a solution for the problem. 
I have a button that insert shortcode in the wp-editor when it is clicked. But when Ckeditor plugin is activated, it gives error of "undefined function 'window.send_to_editor'". I am using

```
window.send_to_editor("[gallery album_id=\"" + id + "\"]");
```

How can i make it work in case of CKeditor. Please help !!

Comment: May be you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671550/jquery-window-send-to-editor

Comment: No its not helpful for me. I need to insert shortcode in [gallery album_id=\"" + id + "\"] format

Comment: Hmm... This might be an obvious question, but where do you define window.send_to_editor? You need that function to be defined before calling it. MoeedFarooqui is correct in that your answer really is in that link, but your problem is either that you forgot to include the definition or you define it too late and it is called before definition. The error message "undefined function 'window.send_to_editor" is quite clear.